# How should I specify the path for an sqlite db in an iPhone project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

After adding it as a resource, the database file itself is in the project root.

I've only been able to open it by specifying the full path as OS X sees it, i.e., "/Users/Louis/Documents/Test Project/test.db".

But of course there is no such path on an iPhone.

I think I should define the path as "application root/test.db" but I don't know how, or if that would even work anywhere else besides my development machine.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Note that in the compiled app bundle the paths won't be the same as in your project. Code and resources go into separate directories. That's why you should use `NSBundle` methods to resolve paths.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the path of the file you've added in XCode you would use pathForResource:ofType: with your mainBundle.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourDb" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

But you can't change files in the mainBundle. So you have to copy it to another location. For example to the library of your app.

You could do it like this:

```
NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *targetPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourDB.sqlite"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:targetPath]) {
    // database doesn't exist in your library path... copy it from the bundle
    NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourDb" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:targetPath error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it helps! You said a bunch there. Am I understanding correctly that I can't write to the database without first copying it to somewhere like the libraryPath? If so, will it stay there as long as the app is installed? And also, if the db is prepopulated I guess this would double its footprint?

Comment: you cannot change anything in your bundle, so you can consider all files you add in xcode as read only. and the database will stay in the library directory until the user deletes your app. It will be included in the backups by itunes too. So if the user switches to a new device and he restores from his backup your database will be there.

Comment: Just an FYI, I had to drag my .sqlite file into the Xcode project itself in order for it to get placed into the bundle, placing it within my project via command line didn't cut it. Hope this helps others stuck on that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Don't just use the SQLite API, use this amazing wrapper called FMDB: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: Are downvotes really necessary for suggesting a more efficient, less painful way of working with SQLite??

Comment: FMDB is a must for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Getting Paths to Standard Application Directories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW6)