# Import my sql file in my iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, file, sqlite, import

I have SQLite Studio fot my Mac OSX, I create there my Schemas, in MySQL I use DBFork Manager a case tool to make my Schemas, I export sql file and then import into MySQL Server, so I want to do the same for my iOS App using SQLite.

I mean, I make my SQLite Schema, then I need to import into my App from a *.sql file, I give my code example using a SQL string... Hope you can help me!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = dirPaths[0];

// Build the path to the database file
_databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                 initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                  @"contacts.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            _status.text = @"Failed to create table";
        }
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    } else {
        _status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
    }
}
[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Comment: And what is the problem? Don't you know how to read a file?

Comment: I know but my problem I think is the Directory of that sql file, for example I add the SQL file in my project, then I use:

NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(???, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

So, wich is the path of my project that will be available when the app is done, and how to convert a NSString to a char, because in the   sqlite_exec(_db, sql_stmt <- HERE is a char, ...); I have to insert a char and not a NSString, and I recover the text of my files as NSData or NSString... and in iOS 6.0 is deprecated:

NSString *textFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a database file in SQLite and want to install it for use on your iPhone.  If you compile it in your program, then it will be in the file bundle.  However, that's read only, so if you want to alter your database at all, you need to copy it to the iphone's documents directory (or another more appropriate directory). Check out the answer to this stackoverflow question:

[SQLite on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042836/how-should-i-specify-the-path-for-an-sqlite-db-in-an-iphone-project)

Comment: Okay thanks, that's mean that I can add the file before compile in the "document" directory, and then change the code of it.

Comment: When you add the file to your project, it ends up in the the project's bundle.  Once your app is installed on the device, your app will have to copy the original database to the documents directory (or another writable directory) before it gets write access to the database. (i.e. you have to open the database in the directory from your app, not the database in the bundle).