# SQLITE : why I can't write on device (iphone) but I can write on simulator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I specify the path for an sqlite db in an iPhone project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042836/how-should-i-specify-the-path-for-an-sqlite-db-in-an-iphone-project)

I wonder why I only can read my Sqlite database on iphone but can't write anything... 
everything work just fine on the simulator..

is there any configuration to set the permission or something??

PS: there is no error while I'm updating or inserting to sqlite (from device).

here's my code (open sqlite) :

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test"
                                                             ofType:@"sqlite"];

        if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
        }
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

and my "update" code :

```
-(void)addCoin:(int)score
{
    NSString *query = @"select coin_user from user where id_user = '1'";
    //query = @"SELECT id_soal FROM soal where jawaban_soal = 'romin'";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int total;
    if (sqlite3_prepare(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)
        == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            total = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update user set coin_user = '%i' where id_user = '1'",total + score];

    if (sqlite3_prepare(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)
        == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_step(statement);
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505192/sqlite-inserts-get-lost-after-app-restart

Comment: You cannot write on sqlite file from main bundle because they are read only.. You have to copy the sqlite file from main bundle to Documents directory then use the sqlite file copied in documents directory.. Hope this help..

Comment: This link may help you for copying https://gist.github.com/1071312

Answer (score 4):

You can't write in your main bundle. You can save data to documents directory
You have to copy your data base to document directory and then have to perform operations on the data base file which is in document directory.

Put this code in app delegate to copy your db

```
NSString* docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString* dbPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Check if the database is existed.
if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:dbPath])
{
    // If database is not existed, copy from the database template in the bundle
    NSString* dbTemplatePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    NSError* error = nil;
    [fm copyItemAtPath:dbTemplatePath toPath:dbPath error:&error];  
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"can't copy db.");
        }
}
```

And init method

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
            NSString* docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
            NSString* dbPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"];

           if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
               NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
           }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You create your sqlite database anywhere and give the path of database. It's easy to you. Check this bellow given code

```
{
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        NSString *lmk= @"Volumes/Outbox/test.sqlite";
        const char *dbpath=[lmk UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB3)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Database is connected sucessfully");
        }
            else
                NSLog(@"Not connected");
            sqlite3_close(contactDB3);
}
```

Now you can do select insert update delete easily.