# sqlite insert working on xcode simulator but not on iphone

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite

I have been working on an app and testing within the simulator in xcode and all working fine, reading from and saving to an SQLITE database.

I have now run this on an iPhone 5, and I can read in from the database fine, but saving to the database is not working.

There are no errors or crashes. Everything runs fine - just the data is not saved on the phone.

I have seen similar questions that are the other way round, working on the device but not the simulator!

Any thoughts or advice appreciated!

Comment: can you post some code my friend???

Comment: Remember the database on the simulator is different from the database on the ios device. If you are making changes to the one you wont see them in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you are trying to update the database in the app bundle - you can't do that, the app bundle is read-only.

("But it worked in the simulator, it really did!" - well, on OS X and in the simulator, restrictions like this aren't always enforced. The simulator is a piece of useless crap, at least considering this point only.)

Comment: For the sake of anyone else looking for sample code to do this, I found this page which also helped fix the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682202/sqlite-why-i-cant-write-on-device-iphone-but-i-can-write-on-simulator